# Upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 failed, now need help to reanimate the system

Tags: upgrade, login

First of all I would like to say Thank you to anyone who tries to help me with this issue.

Second - I am not a *nix user at all, I really wish I had much more experience with this system, but unfortunately I have none.

Now back to my trouble - PREAMBLE (Feel free to skip to AMBLE) - Couple of months ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, just to get some experience with it. I installed Mono+MySql and did some .Net development for a while as I am no Python or Java developer right now. I have no idea why, but my Ubuntu installation was bound to update center in my country (it is Georgia, small but lovely place) and as I gather this Update Center was not getting all the updates, or may be it was holding only important ones. So I had trouble with all those `sudo apt-get ...` commands all the time.

And here comes the AMBLE - Couple of days ago I encountered an article on updating Ubuntu version, which required no more than running `update-manager` and switching to US update center and getting all those updates, **including** Ubuntu 14.10.

So I did all those updates, but I am not sure if I got 14.10 version, as when I logged into the system the background wallpaper still said it was 14.04. Anyway, then I ran 15.04 upgrade.

**Fact 01** : After spending several hours of trying to get into the system I already know that it was bad idea to upgrade 14.04 to 15.04.

During the upgrade to 15.04 my system just stuck at starting MySQL service, as many others did. I waited for couple of hours and then I just shutdown the machine as I had no other idea what to do with it.

As you may already have guessed I cannot get the system alive any more. The system boots up well, but when entering the password it displays some console text screen for a short time and sends me back to the login screen again. Unfortunately it is too fast to get any information out of it.

**What I have tried so far**

1. Try to load the older versions - Restart, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>, select **Advanced Options** select other boot options - same effect in any of them.
2. Get to GRUB configuration screen, but unfortunately I have no idea what to do there.
3. Get to console screen out of boot options menu - same effect.
4. I've found USB Bootable drive from which I've installed 14.04, and tried to run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool from it, no effect...
5. Right now I try to do some silly things, but that's all I can do, unless someone with better knowledge of the system can help me - I ran 'update-manager' in a live session system loaded from flash drive, just hoping for the best - that it would make some changes to the existing system on my hard drive.

I do not need to save any data from my laptop, I just do not want to reinstall it, I really want to make it work. Any help would be appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have another computer, just download 15.10 Version from www.ubuntu.com, burn it to an USB using `unetbootin` http://unetbootin.org/, and boot your Ubuntu-PC with the USB plugged in. On the Ubuntu installation, choose the option "Upgrade".

[image]

This will keep all your files and upgrade your whole system.

If you cannot boot from the USB, change your boot settings in the bios.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Ok, I'm having trouble with "upgrading", the installation says that my computer "has no detected operating systems". This might be because I have selected "Encrypt" option for the previous installation? However I can access the data from "Try Ubuntu" option, by specifying security key... Is there any way to get my old system upgraded?

Comment: It might be, but since you do not need to save any data from the laptop, wouldn't it be better to just perform a fresh install from Ubuntu 15.10?